# Code adapted from D3 v3 to v5 needs an extra update to render correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I found some problems when I tried to adapt code from a [Block](http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9306799) which uses D3 **v3** to ther newer version D3 **v5**.

The chart is not displayed correctly when first executed, however, it will display correctly when updated twice by calling function `changeData`. In D3 v3 the chart is shown straight up. What am I doing wrong ?

Here is the demo showing the error:

```js
let svg;
let radius;
let pie;
let arc;
let outerArc;
let data_ready;
let slice;
let width = 700, height= 400;

let dataChart = [];

svg = d3.select(".chart-d3")
      .append("svg")
      .append("g");
radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2.5;
svg.append("g").attr("class", "slices").attr("name", "slices");
svg.append("g").attr("class", "labels");
svg.append("g").attr("class", "lines");
pie = d3.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d){
     return d.value;
    });

arc = d3.arc()
     .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)
     .innerRadius(radius * 0.4);

outerArc = d3.arc()
     .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
     .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);
svg.attr("transform", "translate (" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")" );

let key = function(d){
  return d.data.label;
}

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
 .domain(["Lorem ipsum", "dolor sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipisicing", "elit", "sed", "do", "eiusmod", "tempor", "incididunt"])
 .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

function randomData(){
 let labels = color.domain();
 let dataFor =  labels.map(function(label){
  return { label : label, value: Math.random() }
 });
 return dataFor;
}

changeData(randomData());

function changeData(data){
 data_ready = pie(data);
 slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice").data(data_ready, key);
 slice
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .style('fill', function(d){ return color(d.data.label) })
  .attr("class", "slice");

 slice
  .transition().duration(1000)
   .attrTween("d", function(d) {
    this._current = this._current || d;
    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
    this._current = interpolate();
    return function(t) {
     return arc(interpolate(t));
    };
   })   
 slice.exit()
  .remove();

 /* ------- TEXT LABELS -------*/
 var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text")
  .data(data_ready, key);

 text.enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) {
   return d.data.label + "(" + Math.round(d.data.value * 1000) + ")";
  });

  text.transition().duration(1000)

  .attrTween("transform", function(d){
   this._current = this._current || d;
   let interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
   this._current = interpolate(0);
   return function(t){
    let d2 = interpolate(t);
    let pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
    pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return "translate(" + pos + ")";
   }
  })
  .styleTween("text-anchor", function(d){
   this._current = this._current || d;
   var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
   this._current = interpolate(0);
   return function(t) {
    var d2 = interpolate(t);
    return midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? "start":"end";
   };
  });

 function midAngle(d){
  return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2;
 }
 
 text.exit()
  .remove();

 /* ------- SLICE TO TEXT POLYLINES -------*/

 var polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline")
  .data(data_ready, key);
 
 polyline.enter()
  .append("polyline");

 polyline.transition().duration(1000)
  .attrTween("points", function(d){
   this._current = this._current || d;
   var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
   this._current = interpolate(0);
   return function(t) {
    var d2 = interpolate(t);
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
    pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return [arc.centroid(d2), outerArc.centroid(d2), pos];
   };   
  });
 
 polyline.exit()
  .remove();
}
```

```css
.chart-d3{
 height: 400px;
 width: 700px;
 margin: 10px auto; box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 3px gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
svg{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
path.slice{
 stroke-width: 2px;
}
polyline{
 opacity: .3;
 stroke: black;
 stroke-width: 2px;
 fill: none;
}
button{
height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="chart-d3">
   <button onclick="changeData(randomData())">Update</button>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of D3 **v4** the behavior of the *general update pattern* has changed. From the [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#selections-d3-selection):

> [*selection*.append](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_append) no longer merges entering nodes into the update selection; use [*selection*.merge](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_merge) to combine enter and update after a data join.

That is why your graphic is broken during the first run; the newly entered elements are not selected and are therefore not transitioned to their final positions. This is cured during the second run as those same elements will all be part of the update selection.

Instead of doing

```
slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice").data(data_ready, key);
slice
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .style('fill', function(d){ return color(d.data.label) })
  .attr("class", "slice");

slice   // <-- This is just the update selection without newly entered elements
  .transition().duration(1000)
```

your code should like this:

```
slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice").data(data_ready, key);
slice = slice     // <══ 2. Store in update selection ══════════════════════╗
  .enter()                                                               // ║
  .append('path')                                                        // ║
  .style('fill', function(d){ return color(d.data.label) })              // ║
  .attr("class", "slice")                                                // ║
  .merge(slice);  // ═══ 1. Merge update selection into enter selection ════╝

slice   // <-- Now, this holds both entered as well as updated elements.
  .transition().duration(1000)
```

Of course, the same needs to be applied to the texts and the polylines.

Have a look at the updated working demo:

```js
let svg;
let radius;
let pie;
let arc;
let outerArc;
let data_ready;
let slice;
let width = 700, height= 400;

let dataChart = [];

svg = d3.select(".chart-d3")
      .append("svg")
      .append("g");
radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2.5;
svg.append("g").attr("class", "slices").attr("name", "slices");
svg.append("g").attr("class", "labels");
svg.append("g").attr("class", "lines");
pie = d3.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d){
     return d.value;
    });

arc = d3.arc()
     .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)
     .innerRadius(radius * 0.4);

outerArc = d3.arc()
     .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
     .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);
svg.attr("transform", "translate (" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")" );

let key = function(d){
  return d.data.label;
}

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
 .domain(["Lorem ipsum", "dolor sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipisicing", "elit", "sed", "do", "eiusmod", "tempor", "incididunt"])
 .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

function randomData(){
 let labels = color.domain();
 let dataFor =  labels.map(function(label){
  return { label : label, value: Math.random() }
 });
 return dataFor;
}

changeData(randomData());

function changeData(data){
 data_ready = pie(data);
 slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice").data(data_ready, key);
 slice = slice
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .style('fill', function(d){ return color(d.data.label) })
  .attr("class", "slice")
    .merge(slice);

 slice
  .transition().duration(1000)
   .attrTween("d", function(d) {
    this._current = this._current || d;
    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
    this._current = interpolate();
    return function(t) {
     return arc(interpolate(t));
    };
   })   
 slice.exit()
  .remove();

 /* ------- TEXT LABELS -------*/
 var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text")
  .data(data_ready, key);

 text = text.enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) {
   return d.data.label + "(" + Math.round(d.data.value * 1000) + ")";
  }).merge(text);

  text.transition().duration(1000)

  .attrTween("transform", function(d){
   this._current = this._current || d;
   let interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
   this._current = interpolate(0);
   return function(t){
    let d2 = interpolate(t);
    let pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
    pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return "translate(" + pos + ")";
   }
  })
  .styleTween("text-anchor", function(d){
   this._current = this._current || d;
   var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
   this._current = interpolate(0);
   return function(t) {
    var d2 = interpolate(t);
    return midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? "start":"end";
   };
  });

 function midAngle(d){
  return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2;
 }
 
 text.exit()
  .remove();

 /* ------- SLICE TO TEXT POLYLINES -------*/

 var polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline")
  .data(data_ready, key);
 
 polyline = polyline.enter()
  .append("polyline").merge(polyline);

 polyline.transition().duration(1000)
  .attrTween("points", function(d){
   this._current = this._current || d;
   var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
   this._current = interpolate(0);
   return function(t) {
    var d2 = interpolate(t);
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
    pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return [arc.centroid(d2), outerArc.centroid(d2), pos];
   };   
  });
 
 polyline.exit()
  .remove();
}
```

```css
.chart-d3{
 height: 400px;
 width: 700px;
 margin: 10px auto; box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 3px gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
svg{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
path.slice{
 stroke-width: 2px;
}
polyline{
 opacity: .3;
 stroke: black;
 stroke-width: 2px;
 fill: none;
}
button{
height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="chart-d3">
   <button onclick="changeData(randomData())">Update</button>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```